# Get maximum value with Zend_Db_Table

Tags: max, zend-db-table

Ive got a Zend_Db_Table

Now I want to get the maximum available value of a field.

Is there a way to get the MAX(number) value or do I need to use basic SQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
new Zend_Db_Expr('MAX(number)')
```

as one of the fields  in the Zend_Db_Table_Select.